# flyspell and ispell give too many spelling suggestions

Tags: flyspell, ispell, spell-checking

I'm using `flyspell` mode with `aspell` under the hood. Emacs 27.1 installed using Homebrew on macOS Mojave. This behavior happens both with my normal configuration as well as `emacs -Q`.

I looked through `M-x customize` as carefully as I could in the `flyspell` and `ispell` sections, but did not find anything useful.

When I right-click on a misspelled word, I get way more suggestions than I want:

[image: screenshot of Emacs with giant menu of spelling suggestions]

I want maybe a dozen suggestions.

`M-x ispell-buffer` similarly gives too many suggestions.

This seems like an Emacs thing because running `aspell` on the same file in the terminal manually gives a much more reasonable number of suggestions (here, 8):

[image: screenshot of aspell]

Comment: @Drew, thanks for the suggestion. I do see it both ways. Question edited.

Comment: Similar question on Stack Overflow with no solutions other than a block of LISP code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is invoking `aspell` as:

```
aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8
```

`-a` is [“pipe mode”](http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-A-Pipe.html). Given this information, I can reproduce the behavior in the terminal:

```
$ echo dbux | aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)
& dbux 47 0: DBUS, Dix, debugs, dubs, debug, box, tux, DBMS, ibex, bxs, daubs, dibs, debuts, deluxe, dybbuks, Durex, Debs, boxy, bugs, dabs, debs, dobs, dub's, dybbuk, tubs, dab's, deb's, DCS, TWX, TeX, Tex, tax, tbs, tex, DC's, TB's, Tb's, daub's, debut's, dybbuk's, Debs's, dibs's, bug's, BC's, Bk's, tub's, Doug's
```

Using the [“ultra”](http://aspell.net/man-html/Notes-on-the-Different-Suggestion-Modes.html) suggestion mode rather than the default “normal” gives five suggestions rather than 47:

```
$ echo dbux | aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8 --sug-mode=ultra
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)
& dbux 5 0: DBUS, debugs, dybbuks, dybbuk's, debarks
```

This can be configured in Emacs by adding `--sug-mode=ultra` to `Ispell Extra Args` in `M-x customize`; it works for me:

[image: 5-item ispell menu]

I would still prefer to get the top dozen or so from normal mode, but this is probably better than it was.

Comment: So far this is the best answer. I'll self-accept but if anything better turns up I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed aspell dictionary. I use `apt install aspell aspell-end` on Debian/Ubuntu.

Then use `M-x flyspell-buffer` to spell check the current buffer. Flyspell is a independent packages which uses a few APIs from ispell. Most user use flyspell instead of ispell these days.

See https://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html for the details.

You can create a plain text personal dictionary `~/.aspell.en.pws` for aspell,

Here is content of sample`~/.aspell.en.pws`,

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 3
ABN
AC
ACN
```

Comment: I do use flyspell (the menu above is from flyspell) and I do have a personal aspell dictionary. I skimmed the link but it's a general how-to on setting up spell checking in Emacs. I don't follow how this answer addresses my issue of too many suggestions.